# Como adicionar a tag de codificação do XML

Tags: sql, xml, servidor, xmldocument, xml-schema

Como adicionar a clausula de codificação do XML

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

QUando você gera o XML atraves do FOR XML PATH conforme exemplo a seguir:

Consulta SQL:

```
   WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http:\\www.oobj.com.br')
select
'1.0' as '@versao',
e.seq_nfe "idLote",
e.cnpj_forn "evento/infEvento/CNPJ",
e.chave_acesso "evento/infEvento/chNFE",
210200 "evento/infEvento/tpEvento",
1 "evento/infEvento/verEvento"

from
MOINHO.dbo.nfe_entrada e

where


e.seq_nfe = 15662


FOR XML PATH('envEventos'), Elements
```

Resultado:

```
<envEventos xmlns="http:\\www.oobj.com.br" versao="1.0"><idLote>15662</idLote><evento><infEvento><CNPJ>25773037000183</CNPJ><chNFE>31170125773037000183550010000661601002373724</chNFE><tpEvento>210200</tpEvento><verEvento>1</verEvento></infEvento></evento></envEventos>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não foi preciso informar a declaração XML.
Usando o FOR XML PATH no SQL SERVER para gerar o resultado da consulta e o assembly que gerou o arquivo XML da forma que o sistema de integração precisava.